# send a string from c++ to java through socket

Tags: java, c++, sockets, utf-8

I have a block of code on the c++ end that would pass a string like this:

```
char someName[100]="Some String here";
    send(sock,someName,sizeof(someName),0);
```

and on the other end I have a java code looking for a string message like this:

```
DataInputStream dIn= new DataInputStream(SOCK.getInputStream());
String filename=dIn.readUTF(); //Looks for "Some String here"
```

the code does not continue and gives a UTFDataFormatException. So I'm basically looking for conversion on c++ someName to UTF-8 format so both ends will be happy!

Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
I tried using BufferedReader on the java code and got something like:

> ‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~‡áø~

Comment: why don't you simply read chars on the Java end?

Comment: @Theolodis Can you please suggest the way how I do it? because clearly BufferedReader isn't working.

Comment: BufferedReader works just fine, you must have not used it correctly.

Comment: @Gimby err.. I used BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream); and String name = br.readLine(); Isn't that correct?

Comment: @Sand just read on the raw socket stream char/byte wise. No need of BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataInputBuffer.ReadUTF() reads in a string encoded in [modified utf-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8), which makes it a bad candidate for reading data that is not encoded with DataOutputBuffer.WriteUTF().

Also, your C++ program sends a fixed length string padded with zero's.  This can also cause problem when the receiver doesn't expect this.

C++11 also supports UTF-8 string literals, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals).

Answer (score -6):

Write the data into a text file from C/C++ application and read that text file from Java application.

Comment: what if these two apps are on different machines (most probably they are if they communicate through sockets) ?

Comment: No problem. You can send a file through socket. and in the other end, read the file

Comment: It is just one string that I want to send over to java program. making a text file somehow seems like extra work to me.Would there be any other way I can get this to work?

Comment: OK, this would work, I guess though it is overkill. But then he would still ask "So I'm basically looking for conversion on c++ someName to UTF-8 format" He would just need it now for writing to the file.

Comment: @Sand I suggest you just Google "encode string utf8 c++"

Comment: @peter.petrov I did infact i ran into the link you posted before but it didn't quite answer my question.

Comment: @Sand No, just Google this. You will find lots of links.

Comment: @Sand. Check other methods in DataInputStream java API.. Did you tried read(Bytes b) method and then converting bytes to String ? or using readLine() method (though readLine method is depricated , once try whether it will work for you or not) 
'DataInputStream dIn= new DataInputStream(SOCK.getInputStream());
String filename=dIn.readLine'

Comment: @Stunner: dIn.readLine(); is deprecated as it will not convert bytes to characters. I am however looking at the using other possibilities and modifying my java code.

Comment: He wants to use a socket and transmitting a file through a socket has the same difficulties than transmitting a string, or more.